# MongoDB Shell: Join a single field from another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection Spots:

```
- spotId
- name
```

and Codes:

```
- codeId
- spotId
- code
```

I want to introduce the field

```
- spotName
```

to Codes (and join by spotId).

How do I update all my existing documents within mongo shell?

When I try $lookup I always get the whole Spot document, not just the name field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get a format where you get `spotName` in each doc, you can use an aggregation pipeline. `$lookup` was a good start. Here it generates the full array, which you may `$unwind` and project necessary stuff

```
[{$lookup: {
        from: 'Spots',
        localField: 'spotId',
        foreignField: 'spotId',
        as: 'new_field'
    }},
{$unwind: '$new_field'},
{$project: {
    codeId: 1,
    spotId: 1,
    code: 1,
    spotName: '$new_field.name'
 }}

]
```

The solution above represents the case if you need to just use the results.

If you indeed want to perform an `update` on the collection, the only way would be to write a `find` which goes through all docs in Codes and then once it gets the doc, it searches a doc in Spots using `findOne`, and then issuing an update statement.

```
Codes.find().each(function(err, doc) {
  Spots.findOne({spotId: doc.spotId}, function (err, item) {
    Codes.update({codeId: doc.codeId}, {$set: {spotName: item.name}}, function (err, res) {})
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run a script

```
var spotMap ={}; Spots.find({},{spotId:1,name:1}).each(function(spot){spotMap[spot.spotId]=spot.name}); Codes.find({}).each(function(code){code.spotName=spotMap[code.spotId]; db.Codes.save(code);});
```

Also note that if the collection is too big, there would be problem while fetching all the data at once due to mongo limit of 16MB data in memory, and then you have to run the script in batches multiple time.

```
Codes.find({}).limit(1000).each(function(code){//do normal stuff}

Codes.find({}).skip(1000).limit(1000).each(function(code){//do normal stuff}

Codes.find({}).skip(2000).limit(1000).each(function(code){//do normal stuff}
```

and so on....